# c++: array of pointer to objects -> program crash when elements are deleted

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, object

I have a pointer Array to objekts of a class "SS_Daten". The class "SS_Daten" has a static instances counter "NumberInstances" that goes up when the construtor of the class is called and goes down when the destructor is called. i run the test with Number = 20.

```
SS_Daten* SSDaten = new SS_Daten[Number];
SS_Daten* ptrSSDaten[Number];

for (int i = 0; i < Number; i++)  {
   ptrSSDaten[i] = &SSDaten[i];
}
```

I can delete all of the array elements without a problem. The counter goes from 20 to 0 like expected.

```
cout << endl << "Number of Instances before: " << SS_Daten::NumberInstances << endl;
delete [] *ptrSSDaten;
cout << endl << "Number of Instances after: " << SS_Daten::NumberInstances << endl;
```

When i delete some (like 5 or 6) of the array elements one by one it workes without a problem but when i delete all of the elements the programm crashes. In case i delete between 10 and 15 it sometimes workes and somethimes crashes.

```
cout << endl << "Number of Instances before: " << SS_Daten::NumberInstances << endl;
delete ptrSSDaten[0];
delete ptrSSDaten[1];
delete ptrSSDaten[2];
delete ptrSSDaten[3];
delete ptrSSDaten[4];
delete ptrSSDaten[5];
.....
delete ptrSSDaten[19];
cout << endl << "Number of Instances after: " << SS_Daten::NumberInstances << endl;
```

---

The array of pointers to objects gets passed around to functions that sometimes delete elements and change the position of the Elements in the array.
**What i need** is a way too clean the rest of the elements up at the end of the main instance like this. But that crashes programm.

```
cout << endl << "Number of Instances before: " << SS_Daten::NumberInstances << endl;
int AA = SS_Daten::NumberInstances;
for (int i = 0; i < AA; i++)    {
    delete ptrSSDaten[i];
}
cout << endl << "Number of Instances after: " << SS_Daten::NumberInstances << endl;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You are only showing pseudo code. For example it is not possible to know if your forgot to assign a suitable value to `ptrSSDaten` or it is just hidden in the code you are not showing.

Comment: You have a major bug in your code, you're not using `std::vector`.

Comment: `SS_Daten* ptrSSDaten[Number];` Is an array of pointers that is not initialized yet. And inside your loop you are using it. It is a UB.

Comment: @Raindrop7 OP is assigning to it in a loop, that's not UB.

Comment: @RickAstley: Thanks! I really didn't notice that

Comment: You *never* allocated them one-by-one, so you can't delete them one-by-one. `delete`-ing them separately is a dangerous operation. As other's have suggested, using a STL container such as `std::vector<>` may make your work easier.

Comment: i have allocated them one by one and now it workes. thanks for the help and the tip with vecor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have undefined behavior.  You use `new[]` to allocate the array.  To get rid of the array you must then use `delete []`.  You cannot call `delete` on the individual elements as they were never allocated with `new`.

I would suggest you use a `std::vector` instead.  If you need to remove an element of the vector you can `erase` it.

Comment: Moreover, if you have to share the elements, you can probably use `shared_ptr` so you make sure that it will be deleted when nothing points to that object.

Comment: @apalomer You probably could, but you should try to avoid it as much as reasonable.

Comment: Why would you? I don't see why avoiding smart pointers. However, I probably not read enough about smart pointers so you might be most likely right.

Comment: @apalomer Generally you wan't to avoid `std::shared_ptr`.  It is a lot more expensive then `std::unique_ptr` (if you really need a pointer this should be your first consideration).  But, you might not even need a pointer at all and, IMHO, that's the best option.